# What are the last two digits of $3^{3^{100}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the last two digits of $3^{3^{100}}$? I had this on an exam, just curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Fermat's little theorem, $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ if $\gcd(a,n)=1$. With $a=3$ and $n=100$, we conclude $3^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}$. Hence if $3^{100}=m\cdot 40+r$, we only need to calculate $3^r\pmod{100}$.

By the same reasoning, we find $3^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{40}$, hene $3^{100}\equiv 3^4=81\equiv 1\pmod {40}$, hence our $r=1$ and ultimately the desired last digits are "03".

Answer (score 0):

Using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), as $\lambda(100)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(25),\lambda(4))=\text{lcm}(20,4)=20$

$$\implies3^{20}\equiv1\pmod {100}\implies 3^{100}=(3^{20})^5\equiv1\pmod {100}$$

We can write $3^{100}=100a+1$ where $a$ is a positive integer

$$\implies3^{3^{100}}=3^{100a+1}=3\cdot (3^{20})^{5a}\equiv 3\cdot 1^{5a}\pmod{100}\equiv3$$